# Doxygen for Python: one paragraph to document both file and package

Tags: python, c++, documentation, doxygen

I have a Python module that is part of a larger project with multiple languages (C++, Matlab, Python, etc.), so we are using Doxygen to document it. I've written a documentation string at the top with the following format.

```
##
# \package mypackage
# \author me
# \brief A one-liner
# \details Lots and lots of lines of usage information
#
```

This correctly displays everything in both the Class List and the Package List of the generated documentation. However, when I click on `mypackage.py` in the File List, I get nothing. I can get it to show up there by replacing `\package` above with `\file`, but then the Class List and Package List have none of the detailed documentation.

Is there an easy way to get Doxygen to put the detailed documentation in both places?

This question holds for `\file` and `\class` documentation in C++ as well.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who lands here, I've settled on the following as the easiest way to implement and maintain this.

```
##    
# \file
# \author me
# \brief A one-liner
# \details Lots and lots of lines of usage information
#

##
# \package mypackage
# \copydoc mypackage.py
#
```